# Stimulate ENTER key from another shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have two shell scripts one.sh and two.sh

I want to execute two.sh from one.sh. Below is the code :

```
#!/bin/sh
sh /home/ubuntu/two.sh
```

The next step ( where I got stuck). There is one point in two.sh when the user have to **press enter to** **continue**.
Next after entering, I need to give the desired directory.
I want to stimulate both the steps from one.sh

Any suggestions ???

Comment: You can try `printf "\n/path/to/dir\n" | sh /home/ubuntu/two.sh`

Comment: Thanks for replying @Mathieu!!!
How can I execute more than one command for the same shell script ?? Like I need to press enter then give directory path and again give yes or no. So How can I execute them with one single command .

Comment: Can you post `two.sh` or at least the command you want to automatize?

Comment: @Mathieu two.sh is too big, but I can post the commands :
1) Press enter to continue 
2) Enter the directory path 
3) To complete Installation ( type yes or no )

These are steps are to be automated !!!

Answer (score 0):

So it worked by using printf, if you know exactly how many y your script is expecting you can do it like this:

```
$ printf 'y\ny\ny\n' | ./script
```

Can find more here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line